# Passive skills in the CV

Tags: word-in-context

Can I divide skills in my CV by "passive" and "active"?

Is there such a notion in English? 
By "active" skills, I mean things I am good at right now. "Passive" is about skills I had in the past. I am not good at them right now, but I can quickly remember them if necessary.

Are there better words? Because the word "passive" seems not positive and I hesitate including it in the CV.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you say, active and passive won't mean anything to an English-speaking reader of your CV/Resume.

I would use *current* for active, and *previous*, *former* (or *lapsed*) skills for what you refer to as passive.

*Lapsed* is the most exactly descriptive for 'passive' in this case, but might have a slightly negative connotation.